# Issue an IP address based on condition, cell value of 1

Tags: excel, vba7

I am trying to create an Excel Function which issues an IP address based on a flag condition. The flag is the presence or absence of a 1.

If a 1 is present then an IP address should be issued.

The function is not taking the flag condition into account and issuing an IP address regardless.

[image: Screenshot of Excel Worksheet]

```vb
Function GetNextIP_002(text As Variant)

Dim ip As String
Dim ip_addr() As String
Dim ip_next As String
Dim cell As Range

ip = text
ip_addr = Split(ip, ".")
ip_next = Trim(Str(Val(ip_addr(3) + 1)))

If ip_next = 256 Then
    ip_next = 0
    ip_addr(2) = 1
End If

For Each cell In Range("E5:E30")
    If cell.Value = " " Then
        GetNextIP_002 = " "
    ElseIf cell.Value = "1" Then
        GetNextIP_002 = ip_addr(0) & "." & ip_addr(1) & "." & ip_addr(2) & "." & ip_next
    End If
Next cell

End Function
```

Comment: Please show what you expect for a result given your data. Also, do you need to use VBA, or can you just use worksheet formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't want to use a for...next loop in a function like this if you are going to use the function in all of those rows. The problem is in G5, the function will loop through all of E5:E30, and output the final result to G5. Then in G6, it will loop through all of E5:E30 again, and output the final result to G6. And so on. Since the last row in your loop E30 has a 1 flag, then anywhere you use this function will end up reading that E30 1 flag.

I've preserved your code as much as possible and moved some things around to make it a sub instead of a function. This should work as you expected:

```
Sub GetNextIP_002()

Dim ip As String
Dim ip_addr() As String
Dim ip_next As String
Dim cell As Range

ip = Range("G4")

For Each cell In Range("E5:E30")
    
    If cell.Value = " " Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2) = " "

    ElseIf cell.Value = "1" Then
        
        ip_addr = Split(ip, ".")
        ip_next = Trim(Str(Val(ip_addr(3) + 1)))
        
        If ip_next = 256 Then
            ip_next = 0
            ip_addr(2) = 1
        End If
        
        ip = ip_addr(0) & "." & ip_addr(1) & "." & ip_addr(2) & "." & ip_next
        cell.Offset(0, 2) = ip
        
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Kevin, thanks very much - your solution is spot on and exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign sequential IP addresses only to the numbers that have `1` in the flag position,I suggest an Excel formula:

Enter in G5 and fill down:

```
=IF(
    E5 = 1,
    TEXTJOIN(
        ".",
        ,
        HEX2DEC(
            MID(
                DEC2HEX(
                    SUM(TEXTSPLIT($G$4, ".") * 256 ^ {3, 2, 1, 0}) +
                        COUNTIF($E$5:E5, 1),
                    8
                ),
                {1, 3, 5, 7},
                2
            )
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

[image]

***Algorithm***

- Split the IP on the dot
- Convert the IP to its base 10 equivalent
- ```
  add 1
  ```
- Convert back to a HEX number with a length of 8
- Split the HEX number into the two character segments
- Convert each segment individually back to a decimal number
- Join the resultant array of decimal numbers with a dot delimiter.

If, for some reason, you want to use a VBA function, I suggest using the same algorithm:

```
Function addIP(ip As String, Optional add As Long = 1) As String
    Dim toDec As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim h
    Dim hx
    
    
h = split(ip, ".")
toDec = 0
For I = 0 To 3
    toDec = toDec + h(I) * 256 ^ (3 - I)
Next I

toDec = toDec + add
hx = Right$("00000000" & Hex(toDec), 8)

ReDim h(3)
For I = 1 To 7 Step 2
    h(Int(I / 2)) = CDec("&h" & Mid$(hx, I, 2))
Next I

addIP = Join(h, ".")

End Function
```

You would then use this on your worksheet as:

```
=IF(E6=1,addIP($G$4,COUNTIF($E$5:E6,1)),"")
```

and fill down.

Comment: Ron, thanks for the help. Both of your solutions work great. I just had to change the E6 to E5 in the formula above and then it was good to go!